# REST + JSON what Protocols are available?

Tags: json, rest, web

I wonder what protocols are standard when it comes to JSON. I need a protocol embedding links with custom relationship attributes.

I am only aware of the Atom / RSS protocol which is XML.

*Update:*

With relationship I refer to the type of the resource link. In Atom the 'rel' attribute is used for it (if I recall correctly).

Comment: Could you provide more details about what you mean by "links with custom relationship attributes"?

Comment: HAL? http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html

Comment: HAL looks promising but it has issues with the currie vs curries notation. I will contact the github owner of the Java port. Thanks for the suggestion.